# Creation of a callback function

Tags: swift

I am trying to create an application using CoreLocation, that also has a protocol `LocationProtocol` with `locationDidFailWithError` function in it, and a separate class `Location`. Here's the function in `Location`:

```
//gets called when user doesn't allow his location to be accessed
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
     self.delegate?.locationDidFailWithError(error: error)
}
```

The `ViewModel` conforms to the `LocationProtocol`. What I need is to show an alert with an option to go to Settings app whenever user denies access to his location in case he wants to still allow the location to be accessed. So I need to create a callback function in the `ViewModel` that can be used in the `ViewController` to show the alert. I have already created the alert with an extension of UIViewController with a function called `alert()`.

How would I create this callback function in the `ViewModel` and use it in the `ViewController`?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a callback closure to viewModel.

```
public var locationAcessDeniedCallBack: (() -> Void)?
```

In viewModel class, invoke this callback closure in the delegate method.

```
func locationDidFailWithError(error: error) {
    locationAcessDeniedCallBack?()
}
```

In the ViewController where you initialise the viewModel add this callback and show the alert inside it.

```
viewModel.locationAcessDeniedCallBack = { [weak self] in 
    self?.showAlert(). //present the UIAlertController here
}
```

Comment: After the initialisation of the viewModel. Where did you initialise the viewModel?

Answer (score 2):

All you need is having a reference to your `ViewController` inside your `ViewModel`. Delegating is a Swift way. You can start with creating a protocol:

```swift
protocol LocationVcInterface: AnyObject {
    
    func showAlert()
    
}
```

This protocol will be holding all actions, which your `ViewController` should be able to do and which your `ViewModel` should be aware of.

After that make your `ViewController` conform this protocol:

```swift
class LocationVC: UIViewController {
    
    func alert() {
        // shows alert
    }
    
}

extension LocationVC: LocationVcInterface {
    
    func showAlert() {
        self.alert()
    }
    
}
```

Then simply add a reference inside your `ViewModel` and make it `weak`:

```swift
class LocationViewModel {
    
    weak var vcInterface: LocationVcInterface?
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        self.delegate?.locationDidFailWithError(error: error)
        vcInterface?.showAlert()
    }
    
}
```

The last thing is to assign a value to this reference somewhere in your code, let's say:

```swift
class LocationVC: UIViewController {
    
    private let viewModel = LocationViewModel()
    
    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibName, bundle: Bundle)
        viewModel.vcInterface = self
    }
    
    func alert() {
        // shows alert
    }
    
}
```